# Moving objects on path

Tags: java, android, path, android-canvas

I'd like to create moving arrows on path, something like this:

[image: moving arrows]

How could it be done?

EDIT:

I've succcessfully created these moving arrows this way: 
I've divided the path into same parts and in the beginning of each part I've placed an arrow. Then positions of all arrows are periodically updated and when they are at the end, I just set their position to start.

Moving the arrow I've implemented using [this example of moving object along path](https://bitbucket.org/TedBeer/spritealongpath). Now the problem is that I'd like to have the arrow in the middle of the path, not over or under it. How could it be done?

This is the onDraw method:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmBackground, rSrc, rDest, null);
    canvas.drawPath(ptCurve, paint);
    //animate the sprite
    Matrix mxTransform = new Matrix();
    if (iCurStep <= iMaxAnimationStep) {
        pm.getMatrix(fSegmentLen * iCurStep, mxTransform,
                PathMeasure.POSITION_MATRIX_FLAG + PathMeasure.TANGENT_MATRIX_FLAG);
        mxTransform.preTranslate(-bmSprite.getWidth(), -bmSprite.getHeight());
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmSprite, mxTransform, null);

        iCurStep++; //advance to the next step
        invalidate();
    } else {
        iCurStep = 0;
    }
}
```

where `pm` is PathMeasure.

Comment: What are you using I see java and Android but what classes more specifically?

Comment: I've reworded the question, now it demonstrates a minimal understanding of the problem being solved - could it be opened again please?

Comment: What do you mean not over or under, but middle?

Comment: Thank you for responses, if you watch [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yeArlQcPbbc), you can see that the image is actually on the line and not centered (centered it would be if the head was above the line and the body under it). On the image I've posted, the arrow is centered on that line (but it is small so it's inside it).

Comment: So your problem is that the arrow rides the side of line but you want it in the center?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem.

Comment: I'll put it in my answer below.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36183/discussion-between-doublemx2-and-dropdropped)

Answer (score 0):

I'll give the data classes. You need to use them to draw.

You'll want a `Position` class to hold the place of an arrow and it'll be used for the path. It should provide access to x and y of `double` type for specific storage, but also cast to `int` type for screen position.

Next, you'll have the `Path` class. It'll have probably an `ArrayList<Position>` to contain the path. You can use these points to draw lines which are the path in the graphics method.

Then, you'll have the `Arrow` class. I'd suggest giving it a position not type `Position` but if `double`. Additionally it should have a field `speed`.
At each update add speed to position.

For drawing purposes you still need to get the place and direction of the arrow. This'll take a class `Vector` which has fields `Position position` and `double angle`.  Then you'll need a method in `Path` , `public Vector getVectorAt(double pos)`. This method should take the position attribute of an `Arrow` and return the `Vector` where the arrow is and is pointing. You can use the return to draw it.

I plan on attempting this when I get a chance, maybe I'll update this later for some source.

---

As for setting the arrow in the center of the line you could try:

```
mxTransform.preTranslate(-bmSprite.getWidth()/2, -bmSprite.getHeight()/2);
```

instead of the line you have using `Matrix.preTranslate(...)`. I can't exactly emulate what you have without the entire user class(es), so this may not work.